# Is there any use for WSDL file in REST or JSON web service?

Tags: java, json, rest, wsdl

Is there any use for WSDL file in REST/JSON web service?

Is there any other way to let the clients publish the list of services available in a REST/JSON web service?

Comment: WSDL is for SOAP based webservices, REST services have WADL

Comment: please read this article: http://bitworking.org/news/193/Do-we-need-WADL by Joe Gregorio.
And this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626021/json-rest-soap-wsdl-and-soa-how-do-they-all-link-together